# module does not recognize components even though they are declared

Tags: angular

module does not recognize components, im using angular 13. When i did this code in 14 version, it worth. Anyone knows something about it?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent,
    CardComponent,
    ChartFaturamentoComponent,
    ChartVerbaComponent,
    ChartTermometroComponent,
    ChartVerbaDiariaComponent,
    CardPeriodoComponent,
    SignInComponent,
    TesteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule,FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,NgModule,NgChartsModule,RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My module

(element) app-teste: HTMLElement
'app-teste' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-teste' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-teste' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message

error

Comment: Consider being more descriptive of your problem, including providing an errors you are receiving, along with all relevant code snippets.
For example: Which components are not being recognised? What error makes you think this is the case?

Comment: what error does the build throw  ?

Comment: sorry guys, is my first time here.

Comment: (element) app-teste: HTMLElement
'app-teste' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-teste' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-teste' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message

Comment: You are probably missing out something. Are you creating the component using the angular cli? Provide the code for your component.

Comment: Also, where are you using this component?

Comment: This TesteComponent i use angular/cli. Im using in app html